# "Resource.Id" does not contain a definition "Home"

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am having a bit of trouble getting `Home` in `Android.Resource.Id` to be recognized. If I do `global::Android.Resource.Id.Home`, it works, but I want to try to avoid using `global::`. I cleaned the project and rebuilt, many times. I also tried removing the `Resource.Designer.cs` file, but it was not regenerated because of all the missing references to the file. Can anyone help with this issue?

Comment: You tried deleting the bin and obj folders? Sometimes clean/rebuild is not enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have Android in your namespace, which is why it only works when you use global:: infront.

Comment: Thanks, yes I had the word `Android` in my namespace.